# Pass sql expression with GetParameterAsText to SelectLayerbyAttribute in .py script

Tags: arcpy, sql, arctoolbox, select-by-attribute, error-000358

With Arctoolbox and python scripting I'm creating long tool, but one of the steps is to select by attributes with SQL expression.
Let's imagine that:

`featureCar = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)` is Data Type/Feature Set: attributes `weight`, `length`, `height`

`filter = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)` is Data Type/SQL Expression.

```
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
```

In addition, when I run a tool from arctoolbox and previously specify in sql expression:

`"weight" > 2000 AND "length" > 2 AND "height" > 1` from `featureCar` with assistance of Query Builder

I'm expecting that this query as it is will be passed to `arcpy.SelectbyAttribute_management`, but it seems not. How to pass this expression correctly to `arcpy.SelectbyAttribute_management` in  python script?
I've tried:

`arcpy.SelectbyAttribute_management(featureCar, "NEW_SELECTION", "(filter)")`, and similar solutions with quoting `filter`, but I always get ERROR 000358: Invalid expression. 
I've noticed that is something with `'\'{}\''.format(filter)`, but don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

A few things...

- `filter` is a reserved name in Python (it's a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)) so
  you shouldn't use that as a variable name.
- your where clause is already a string as you are using `GetParameterAsText()` to
  return it as a string, so no need to put it inside quotes.  You
  should try something like this:

reference your where clause like this:

`where = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)`

and pass it in like this:

`arcpy.SelectbyAttribute_management(featureCar, "NEW_SELECTION", where)`